# How to ignore empty key = value in an INI file

Tags: c#, ini

I have a setup that reads an ini file to get the info to insert into a send email layout.
My problem is if the ini file has any blank spots in the ccto and bccto areas it will not send the email. If i // the lines out it does work perfect for me. so i am stumped on this. and yes new to c#

```
INIFile inif = new INIFile(@"c:\test\mailsettings.ini");

try
{
     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
     mail.From = new MailAddress("reports@xxxxx.com");
     mail.To.Add(inif.Read("Properties", "personto"));
     mail.CC.Add(inif.Read("Properties", "ccto"));
     mail.Bcc.Add(inif.Read("Properties", "bcto"));
     mail.Subject = inif.Read("Properties", "site") + " End Of Day Report";
     mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
     mail.Body = "Greetings, attached is your End-of-Day Report.<br/> If you have any questions or concerns about this report please contact VersiPOS Client Services at support@versipos.com or by calling us at (800) 655-7349.<br/> + <img src='C:\\test\\1.jpg'/>";
}
```

Comment: Very simple, check for the value before you add it.

Answer (score 3):

Check the content of those two values first, and if there is a value, add it, otherwise they will remain null and won't affect the sending of the email.

```
INIFile inif = new INIFile(@"c:\test\mailsettings.ini");

            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("reports@xxxxx.com");
                mail.To.Add(inif.Read("Properties", "personto"));
                var ccto = inif.Read("Properties", "ccto");
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ccto))
                    mail.CC.Add(ccto);
                var bcto = inif.Read("Properties", "bcto");
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bcto))
                    mail.Bcc.Add(bcto);
                mail.Subject = inif.Read("Properties", "site") + " End Of Day Report";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "Greetings, attached is your End-of-Day Report.<br/> If you have any questions or concerns about this report please contact VersiPOS Client Services at support@versipos.com or by calling us at (800) 655-7349.<br/> + <img src='C:\\test\\1.jpg'/>";
            }
```

Comment: They will not always have a value there. and the ini file is like this.                            [Properties]
site=eric's funny demo
personto=keith@xxxx.com
ccto=
bcto=

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why you want to check first, before directly adding empty strings to the mail properties that are problematic.

Comment: Yes and what is it that would need to do for this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are asking. You said that if you comment out those 2 lines where ccto and bcto are set, it works, and you said the problem happens when these two have no values in the .ini file, so the code checks whether there are blanks before adding them to the object. Are you saying that it still doesn't work with those if statements in place?

Comment: sorry my bad, if i do this in the code it works "// mail.CC.Add (data["Properties"]["ccto"]);"  or if i remove them from the ini file completely it works fin. but I do need them both still there as I nvere know what ones is needed per site.

Comment: @KeithW I'm sorry, but I don't understand what is the problem. Maybe you can give an example of an .ini file entry that does not work and point out why exactly you think it does not work.